# How do I flip the bits in a vector in VHDL

Tags: rotation, vhdl

I have a problem with VHDL, I want to rotate the signal Checked1 and save it in itself:

```
Checked1<=to_stdlogicvector(to_bitvector(Checked1) ROR 1);
```

and I get all zeros, instead of 0100->0010
I know I can't use the same signal, but I have to change Checked1 in a loop.

How can i used it?

The whole code is here:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_arith.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Stall_control is
Port ( EP : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
SP : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
Comp : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
Position : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR  (7 downto 0));
end Stall_control;

architecture Behavioral of Stall_control is

type state is (LOOP_STATE, END_STATE);

signal FSM_state: state;

signal Check: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR  (7 downto 0);
signal Checked: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR  (7 downto 0);
signal Checked1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR  (7 downto 0):="00000000";

signal flag: STD_LOGIC:='0';
begin
Checked<= EP;
process(EP, SP, Comp, Check, CheckED, CheckED1, FLAG)
begin


Position<= "11111111";

    case FSM_state is

        when LOOP_STATE=>
            if((Checked AND Comp)="00000000") OR ((Checked1 AND Comp)="00000000") then
                Checked1<=to_stdlogicvector(to_bitvector(Checked1) ROR 1);

                --Checked<=Checked1;

                --Checked1(7 downto 0)<=Checked1(0)&Checked1(7 downto 1);

                flag<='0';

                if(CheckED1/= SP) then
                    FSM_state<=LOOP_STATE;
                else
                    FSM_state<=END_STATE;
                end if;

            else
                flag<='1';
                FSM_state<=END_STATE;
            end if;

        when END_STATE=>
            if flag='1' then
                    Position<= Checked1;
            else
                    --Position<= Checked1;
                    Position<= "11111111";
            end if;
    end case;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: i tried loop, and then that FSM, the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You are never assigning anything but all '0's to checked1.

```
case fsm_state is

    when loop_state =>
        if (checked  and comp) = "00000000" or 
           (checked1 and comp) = "00000000" then

            checked1 <= to_stdlogicvector(to_bitvector(checked1) ror 1);

            flag<='0';

            if checked /= sp then
                fsm_state<=loop_state;
            else
                fsm_state<=end_state;
            end if;

        else
                flag<='1';
            fsm_state<=end_state;
        end if;
```

checked1 has a default value of (others => '0') (all zeros) and is only rotated by 1.  Of course it's going to be all zeros.

> -- The ror operator returns a value that is L rotated right by R index positions. That is, if R is 0 or if L is a null array, the return
>   value is L. Otherwise, a basic rotate operation replaces L with a
>   value that is the result of a concatenation whose right argument is
>   the leftmost (L'Length - 1) elements of L and whose left argument is
>   L(L'Right). If R is positive, this basic rotate operation is repeated
>   R times to form the result. If R is negative, then the return value is
>   the value of the expression L rol -R.

It sounds like you want a different default value for checked1.

You don't need the ROR operator, you can use concatenation:

```
checked1 <= checked1(0) & checked1 (7 downto 1);
```

(Because your ROR operator R value is a constant and within the length of checked1).

And none of these now commented out packages are needed in your context clause:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
-- use ieee.numeric_std.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Not a one of the three, and there can be potential conflicts from the combination.

And the way the process sensitivity list is populated, you've created an oscillation, any signal assigned in the process that is also in the sensitivity list will cause the process to resume the next simulation cycle.  Put a '1' somewhere in the default value for checked1 and rotating it will cause an event (a change of value) on checkd1 causing the process to be invoked successively.

Comment: I use the values:

EP="01000000" , SP="00000001", Comp="1000000" THEN

EP="01000000" , SP="00000001", Comp="0001000" THEN

EP="01000000" , SP="00000001", Comp="0000000" THEN

EP="01000000" , SP="00000001", Comp="0000011"

so i change onle the Comp values, all i want is to put the value of EP in changed (or changed1) and then see what's the result of (changed1 AND comp) if it's 0's, i want to Rotate Right the changed1 and loop again (changed1 AND comp) until i have somewhere a 1, or Checked1=SP. All i want is to rotate Changed1 until i get the value i want in the operation (changed1 AND comp)

Comment: You said: "You don't need the ROR operator, you can use concatenation:

   checked1 <= checked1(0) & checked1 (7 downto 1);" i cant have the right value, i have UUUUU's

Comment: Your comment shows Comp values that have  a bit_string length of 7, which Comp has a length of 8.  There is no assignment to check anywhere.  I see checked1 as "00000000" always and fsm_state = end_stat, which says you're changing state during initialization (every process runs at least once at initialization). check is always "UUUUUUUU" because it is never assigned. This will drop you directly into end_state where it will stay, exactly as you wrote it to do. So you are actually never assigning to checked1 either. Without knowing what this is for, can you make the process sequential (clocked)?

Comment: it's 8bits, my mistake in typing

Comment: Which changes do i have to do, to make that work... i am very confused! Also i cant use clock... it has to be asychronus

Comment: There are several basic issues.  Your original question was limited to checkd1 behavior, the limitation cause by a lack of a '1' bit to move around, there being no other assignment to checked1.  A second is a zero delay sequencer (delta cycles only) doesn't represent hardware (outputs are glitches as best). The H in VHDL is Hardware. Third you're 'design' isn't expressed as Quasi-Delay Insensitive and zero timed models end up with isochronic forks which can cause trivial changes to break the model with introduced delta delay.  I don't think you can get your design to work in it's present form.

Comment: By introducing uniform output delays (e.g. after 1 ns) and tinkering with default or initial values I could get your model to do shifts. However I couldn't also get it to recognize when to stop shifting. Everything that added delta delays or additional output delays (again uniform) would break something else.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to break the process into a bunch of processes or other concurrent statements that among other things made it clear what was state and what wasn't.  This would involve adding signals like crazy for things that are evaluated in if statements.  It sounds like you should do some basic reasearch on asynchronous state machines first.